# Splitting words and take specific words

Tags: python, regex

I have a problem with my python script, it's a straightforward problem but I can't resolve it.
For example, I have 11 words text and then I split using `re.split(r"\s+", text)` function

```
import re

text = "this is the example text and i will splitting this text"
split = re.split(r"\s+", text)
for a in (range(len(split))):
    print(split[a])
```

The result is

```
this
is
the
example
text
and
i
will
splitting
this
text
```

I only need to take 10 words from 11 words, so the result I need is only like this

```
is
the
example
text
and
i
will
splitting
this
text
```

Can you solve this problem? It will very helpful
Thank you!

Comment: You can use `range(1, len(split))` to start the counter at 1 instead of 0.

Answer (score 1):

Just index like that

```
>>> import re
>>>
>>> text = "this is the example text and i will splitting this text"
>>> split = re.split(r"\s+", text)
>>> split
['this', 'is', 'the', 'example', 'text', 'and', 'i', 'will', 'splitting', 'this', 'text']
>>> split[-10:]
['is', 'the', 'example', 'text', 'and', 'i', 'will', 'splitting', 'this', 'text']
```

Answer (score 1):

No need of regex:

```py
text = "this is the example text and i will splitting this text"
l = text.split()  # Split with whitespace
l.pop(0)          # Remove first item
print(l)          # Print the results
```

**Results**: `['is', 'the', 'example', 'text', 'and', 'i', 'will', 'splitting', 'this', 'text']`

See [Python proof](https://tio.run/##HcvBCoAgEATQu18xeNJLBJ37GCHJhU2XXMi@3lKYw8CbkVdTyVvvGptih9VEFX80RcQWLuGIaSEfIDzEjCpMqpRPzPVga/h/j7ZMdd7wIkXc6o3clNWx7/0D).